# How to pass values that are in a List Object in C#?

Tags: c#

This maybe a simple one. That is I have a some JSON details which comes as a list and then it converts to object. So now the object contains 2 values since it is a list. So I wanted to pass them into the database. How do I achieve this.

Here's what I tried.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostRegister([FromBody] dynamic register)
{
    try
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray qualificationRes = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)register.qualification;
        var qualification = qualificationRes.ToObject<List<Qualification>>(); //conversion to the List object
        var sta2 = QMgrt.InsertQualifications(qualification,nid); //passing of List value.
        return Ok("success");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return Ok("fail");
    }
}
```

This is how I trying to insert it to the database

```
public bool InsertQualifications(List<Qualification> quali,int newid) //Getting the List values
{ 
    foreach (Qualification q in quali) // This is where the issues comes only one set of object is passed to the database
    { 
        try
        {
            var status = db.AddQualiDetails("Insert_QualiDetails", q.Description, q.University, q.Date_of_award, q.Qauli_id, q.Quali_type, newid, q.Duration);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For more reference I have added this screenshot
[image]

As seen in the screenshot there are two set of object. How do I pass all of them into the database. Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you right but maybe this could be the problem:

```
public bool InsertQualifications(List<Qualification> quali,int newid) //Getting the List values
{ 
    foreach (Qualification q in quali) // This is where the issues comes only one set of object is passed to the database
    { 
        try
        {
            var status = db.AddQualiDetails("Insert_QualiDetails", q.Description, q.University, q.Date_of_award, q.Qauli_id, q.Quali_type, newid, q.Duration);
            return true; <<<<<-------
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

You insert one List entry into your database and the `return true;` 
When you use `return` you exit the method and stop the `foreach`.
Regarding to this, your code is adding only one entry of your list.
Try to just remove this `return true;`

Also check any exception occurred during the insertion.

Comment: Yup. Removing of the `return true` solved my issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i see you didn't call `db.SaveChanges()`. `SaveChanges` will commit your changes to database. Also there is `return true;` in your loop, it breaks the loop.

Here is correct code to save your data to database:

```
public bool InsertQualifications(List<Qualification> quali,int newid) //Getting the List values
    { 

        foreach (Qualification q in quali) // This is where the issues comes only one set of object is passed to the database
        { 
            try
            {
                var status = db.AddQualiDetails("Insert_QualiDetails", q.Description, q.University, q.Date_of_award, q.Qauli_id, q.Quali_type, newid, q.Duration);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the return true helped me solve the issue. Thanks. :)